# vb.NET Drag&Drop between two tabpages in the same tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have two datagridviews and I drag & drop between them.
But now I have to put them in two tabpages in the same tabcontrol.
Pages must change during drag & drop when I move mouse to the desired page title while left button is down. How can I do?
Thank you

Comment: You need the GiveFeedback event.  Control.MousePosition tells you where the mouse is located, TabControl.PointToClient() gives you its position relative to the tabs.  Iterate the tabs, compare to their GetTabRect() to see if it hovers a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replay!
This is my code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.GiveFeedback
        Dim position As Point = TabControl1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)
        For id As Integer = 0 To TabControl1.TabCount - 1
            If TabControl1.GetTabRect(id).Contains(position) Then
                TabControl1.SelectedIndex = id
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

it works but not if I just move between the titles of tabpages